# How to get firebase local Authentication State Persistence value

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm new to React Native and Firebase coding. I'd like to skip the login process if the user logged in successfully last time. According to Firebase doc, firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL can persist the authentication state even the activity is destroyed. The problem is how can I check the local persisted authentication state when the app initializes?

I managed to use AsyncStorage to achieve the goal, but firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL is supposed to be the simpler approach, but I can't figure it out. 
Init codes:
`<pre>
componentWillMount() {
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
      authDomain: "xxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://xxxx.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "xxxxxx",
      storageBucket: "xxxxx.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx"
    };
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      console.log("call firebase init");
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      console.log(firebase.app().options);
    }
  }
</pre>`

Comment: "The problem is how can I check the local persisted authentication state when the app initializes?" Why do you want to do that? If the auth data was persisted and you set the persistence, then Firebase should pick up and refresh the auth state automatically upon restart. If that doesn't happen, edit your question to show the [minimum code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, what I want to do is to allow user automatically login like gmail app or chat apps, even the apps has been killed. Because Firebase initializes again after the app restarts (am I wrong?), how does Firebase pick up the auth state. Here is the init codes, does firebase.auth() pick up the auth state?

Comment: Yes, if the data was persisted (which happens by default on most supported platforms), it will be reloaded, and revalidated, upon app restart.

Comment: I put **firebase.auth()** in constructor to try to get currentUser but got null. I guess it returns a promise. How can I get currentUser before component mount? I put **firebase.auth()** in **async componentWillMount()** still got null user. Sorry I'm new to react native. The codes in constructor: 
<pre>
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);      firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
let loginUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
console.log({ loginUser });
</pre>

Comment: Picking up the current user may require a token refresh, which takes an asynchronous call to the server. For that reason you should use a listener to pick up that user. See the first code snippet in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, the listener works. But it takes around 5 seconds to pick up the authorized user in my simulator. At least I know it works. Thanks.

Comment: Given that refreshing the user's token requires a interaction with the server, the 5 seconds sounds a bit long but not unreasonable.